# jquery mobile swipe functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I have a swipe function set up on a web app for ipad so that once a user swipes right wit their finger, it takes them to the last page they went to. That javascript looks like this

```
    <script>
$(document).bind('swiperight', function () {
        history.back();
    });</script>
```

Now with that in mind, if I wanted to make the function more exact, so that it would change to a particular page, would I incorporate the JQM change page function?

```
    <script>
$(document).bind('swiperight', function () {
       $.mobile.changePage( "#home", { transition: "slide"} );
    });</script>
```

And where would I put the attribute for data-direction="reverse"?

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
$(document).bind('swiperight', function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("#home", {
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: true
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like it should work, but some reason it isn't I'll mess around with it and see whats up. Thanks